# How to update my profile photo in Contacts App from another application in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to update the profile photo and name for the User Profile in Contacts App from another app in Android. I could not find any way to do that. I have referred [Android documentation to modify contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data) and [Android documentation for User Profile](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#UserProfile). Can anyone suggest how to update profile photo and name from another application?

Answer (score 0):

You‘d want to sent a Contact.Intent from the App with the coresponding data so that the Contact App can handle the Intent and update the coresponding contact.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do but I could not figure out 'user profile' is what type of contact. Or is it stored differently than other contacts in the contacts App?